# Media queries for tablet min-resolution and max-resolution

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Currently working on a responsive design website. I use media query for targeting different devices based on the width and screen resolution.

1. I have a scenario were i wanted to use the screen resolution to target the devices, but i don't understand how this works.
2. I wanted to check both min-width and max-width, with that the screen resolution may also range from 97dpi to ipad max resolution 264dpi. But this does not seems to work. If i give a single resolution min-width:155dpi for hp loaded tablet it works. But min to max resolution condition seems not working. Could you guys share your idea.

For this i have used like the below code

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) 
and (max-width:1024px) and (min-resolution:96dpi) and (max-resolution:264dpi){
```

Answer (score 9):

The `resolution` media query [doesn't have good support in webkit browsers yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/resolution#Browser_compatibility) so you may have more success using `device-pixel-ratio` instead.

http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/

So we can restate your media query using `resolution` for those browsers that understand it (Firefox, IE9+, Opera), and `device-pixel-ratio` for all things webkit (Chrome, Safari, iOS and Android):

```
@media only screen and (min-resolution:96dpi) and (max-resolution:264dpi) and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px),
       only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px) {}
```

Comment: I'd argue (a year after you wrote this) that it's a good time to switch (since Chrome 29, we're now on 34, and since Firefox 16, current version 29).  Also Chrome is encouraging people to switch from dpi to dppx in console messages.  It's nice to avoid the doubling up with the webkit prefix too and writing a logical OR statement with media queries is tricky (although 'or' is denoted by commas, you can't easily combine an 'and' and an 'or' in a single statement in my experience).

Comment: **Edit** spoke too soon - support for 'resolution' still pretty awful in mobile, unfortunately... :(

Answer (score 0):

These MQs will handle the preset settings in the Windows8.1 simulator:

```
@media screen and (resolution: 96dpi) and (max-width: 512px) and (device-aspect-ratio: 1024/768),
  screen and (resolution: 96dpi) and (max-width: 683px) and (device-aspect-ratio: 1366/768),
  screen and (resolution: 96dpi) and (max-width: 960px) and (device-aspect-ratio: 1920/1080),
  screen and (resolution: 96dpi) and (max-width: 1280px) and (device-aspect-ratio: 2560/1440) {
  body {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-resolution: 130dpi) and (max-resolution:140dpi) and (max-width: 960px) and (device-aspect-ratio: 1920/1200),
  screen and (min-resolution: 130dpi) and (max-resolution:140dpi) and (max-width: 720px) and (device-aspect-ratio: 1440/1080),
  screen and (min-resolution: 130dpi) and (max-resolution:140dpi) and (max-width: 960px) and (device-aspect-ratio: 1920/1080) {
  body {
    background-color: violet !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-resolution:  174dpi) and (min-resolution: 172dpi) and (max-width: 1280px) and (device-aspect-ratio: 2560/1440)  {
  body {
    background-color: purple !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to older measurement by Quircksmode
http://quirksmode.org/tablets.html

```
@media screen and (min-width: 37em) {
}
```

however, this doesn't work best for newer tablets I guess, since my phone has 37em or more.

What about:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 42em) {
}
```