# Bootstrap 3 - Grid Breakpoints for responsive design and Hi Res Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently bootstrap has breakpoints for their gird system / different size screens set by size in pixels:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

However, with phones now being super high resolution and sometimes having 1080p screens, it displays the tablet or desktop layouts on some phones which is still a bit useless. Is there someway to manage this by looking at pixel density or similar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Media queries for tablet min-resolution and max-resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924032/media-queries-for-tablet-min-resolution-and-max-resolution)

Answer (score 2):

You might look into setting Em's instead of pixel based breakpoints since ems are based on the font size, zoom and several other factors to enable the break point.

Well, ultimately, if you’re using pixels it will literally be that strict. For example, say we have a media query that is like so;

@media (max-width: 500px) {
   rules here...
}

It will force that 500px as the breakpoint, regardless of the base font size or zoom level. You can imagine how this might be a problem if, for example, your user zooms to a factor of 10, the width of the browser is still going to be the determining factor as a breakpoint, so it might completely ruin your beautifully designed website.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful tip as this has been something that I haven't considered before and will definitely look into this. Let's say i've specified something as max width 500px, should i specifying that as 500em, instead?

Comment: No if you want to specify something as 500px width then you need to think of em as a measurement of the default font size which if the browser front size default is 16px which it is then 1em =16px. So in-order to achieve 500px equivalent using ems it would be 31.250em or 500px/16p =31.25em. A good example of using ems for responsive design and breakpoints would be to look into Foundation and how they structure their breakpoints.

Comment: Here is another great tool for getting used to calculating using ems http://riddle.pl/emcalc/