# Change website color profile based on platform?

Tags: css, colors

I've been working on web coding and just launched my first website. I made it on my MacBook Pro Retina 13 inch. This MBP screen displays bright and clean colors. But if I test it on other screens (for example, Windows PC's), my site will display too light colors. Its really bothering me cause many people own a Windows PC.

I want to know if it's possible to change the color profile on different platforms? Perhaps via CSS, Javascript or Media Queries?

This is the site (sorry for the foreign language, it's dutch): http://www.sallas.nl/nieuw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find some information here:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Generally the media queries are something like:

```
@media (min-resolution: 192dpi){
}
```

The support for this isn't great, especially on mobile browsers.

You might want to look here:

[Media queries for tablet min-resolution and max-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924032/media-queries-for-tablet-min-resolution-and-max-resolution)