# Zoom website depending on monitor resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming, resolution

I'm looking for a javascript to change the zoom of the website depending on the viwewers screen resolution. I made the website on my desktop with 1920x1080p :/

```
html { -moz-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75); zoom: 0.75; zoom: 75%; }
```

I got this in my css to zoom the website to my liking for MacBook (1280 x 800).

However I have no idea how to enable/disable it using javascript (if its possible?) and how to detect the resolution.

Any help is appriciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

css @media queries will help you,don't need javascript.for example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  html {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
    zoom: 0.75;
    zoom: 75%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  html {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.50, 0.50);
    zoom: 0.50;
    zoom: 50%;
  }
}
```

if you specifically want javascript then look at window screen object [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp)

```
 <script>alert("Screen Width: " + screen.width);</script>
```

Comment: I copied everything you wrote, changed scrren to screen because I figured it was a typo, I also changed 1280px to 1440px because apparently Mac had a higher resolution. But it doesnt seem to work :o

Comment: sorry it didn't work have a look at [w3schools @media](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). there all sorts of different ways to try it. have a look at the second answer I've just found [HERE, SO media queries question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924032/media-queries-for-tablet-min-resolution-and-max-resolution)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
@media(max-device-width:1280px){
  html{
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
    zoom: 0.75;
    zoom: 75%;
  }
}

@media(max-device-width:800px){
  html{
    -moz-transform: scale(0.50, 0.50);
    zoom: 0.50;
    zoom: 50%;
  }
}
```