# zoom depending on browser resolution / browser screen size

Tags: css

i was reading here about zoom

[Zoom website depending on monitor resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908509/zoom-website-depending-on-monitor-resolution)

and it seems nothing works

I want to test the browser width / browser view port and then, if it is a high number, I want to automatically have the web page zoomed to say, 110%

cross browser compatible.

how to do it?

Comment: It might be worth considering other methods for responsive design as trying to control a setting that a user sets at their preference could easily get frustrating for your users.

Comment: @JamesCoyle I agree 100%. But clients sometimes have a bit funny ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better approach to achieve this using responsive design.
Calculate every element in **rem** unit so that as you change the font-size on root element; all of your element's looks bigger/smaller on screen through desire media quires.

i.e: let suppose you have a `div` and `h1` elements and you want to show bigger/smaller on different screen then you should follow the code:

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

<style>
div{
   height: 25rem;
   border:1px solid red;
  }
h1{
   font-size: 4rem;
  }
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  html{
   font-size: 16px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
      html{
       font-size: 20px;
      }
    }


  </style>
```

So in above code the `div` and `h1` tag should be big or small as you change your font-size on html tag depending upon media query breakpoints.

Comment: agreed. Notice: I actually did this for mobile phones, as users usually are a lot closer to the screen on mobile so I sized down font size. What is noteworthy is that images will cause problems that you insert without defined `rem` height and width as those will not resize well. As well the typical px in for example borders, should be avoided. And it's a good idea to set the default html font-size to 10px. That way 1 standard pixel is 0.1rem.

Comment: You can set `font-size: 62.5%;`  on the `html` tag. That way all of your rem values are the pixel value divided by 10. So `1.6rem = 16px` etc. assuming the default browser font size is `16px`. This then allows the user to set their own font size in the browser settings.